# How to get element content using only XPath and C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath

I've found a lot of articles about how to get node content by using simple XPath  expression and C#, for example:

XPath:

```
/bookstore/author/first-name
```

C#:

```
string xpathExpression = "/bookstore/author/first-name";

nodes = navigator.Select(xpathExpression);
```

I wonder how to get content that is inside of an element, and the same element is inside another element and another and another.
Just take a look on below code:

```
<Cell>          
    <CellContent>
        <Para>                               
            <ParaLine>                      
                <String>ABCabcABC abcABC abc ABCABCABC.</string> 
            </ParaLine>                      
        </Para>     
    </CellContent>
</Cell>
```

I only want to extract content `ABCabcABC abcABC abc ABCABCABC.` from `String` element.

Do you know how to resolve problem by use **XPath expression** and **.Net C#**?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After [googling `c# .net xpath`](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=c#%20.net%20xpath) for few seconds you'll find [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333), which provides example which you can easily modify to use [`XPathDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathdocument.aspx), [`XPathNavigator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathnavigator.aspx) and [`XPathNavigator::SelectSingleNode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50wkzt09.aspx):

```
XPathNavigator nav;
XPathDocument docNav;
string xPath;

docNav = new XPathDocument("c:\\books.xml");
nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();
xPath = "/Cell/CellContent/Para/ParaLine/String/text()";

string value = nav.SelectSingleNode(xPath).Value
```

I recommend more reading on [xPath syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx). Much more.

Comment: I've had to deal with XPathNavigator, XPathDocument... . Problem is that file doesnt look like a simple xml. I mean <NameElement1><NameElement2>abababababababa</NameElement2></NameElement1>. One element include another element, here: <NameElement1<NameElement2 <NameElement3 abababababababa>>>. So simple XPath syntax doesn't work "/Cell/CellContent/Para/ParaLine/String/text()";. I ask about sth other solution then simple xpath expresion.

Comment: @mazury than it's not valid XML and you cannot use `xPath`

Answer (score 4):

You can use Linq to XML as well to get value of specified element

```
var list = XDocument.Parse("xml string").Descendants("ParaLine")
                 .Select(x => x.Element("string").Value).ToList();
```

From above query you will get value of all the string element which are inside ParaLine tag.

Answer (score 3):

```
navigator.SelectSingleNode("/Cell/CellContent/Para/ParaLine/String/text()").Value
```