# Xpath query cdata

Tags: c#, xpath

How can I use xpath to get the value **f89dcc8012314bb9b0de723f308bee49** from the xml? the value could exists at any level.

```
<root>     
<item>
       <category><![CDATA[umb://document/f89dcc8012314bb9b0de723f308bee49]]></category>
     </item>
   <item>
<label>
           <category><![CDATA[umb://document/f89dcc8012314bb9b0de723f308bee49]]></category>
</label>
     </item>
</root>
```

Comment: have you checked this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012390/how-to-get-element-content-using-only-xpath-and-net-c-sharp

Comment: That string appears twice; does it make a difference from which of the two `category` nodes you extract it?

Comment: To help you with this, we need to understand what you know about the document, and what you don't know. Presumably you don't know that the string in question is f89dcc8012314bb9b0de723f308bee49, because if you did, then you wouldn't need a query. So if you don't know that, what do you know? If you tell us, for example, that you are looking for the content of the first category element in the document, then we have something to go on. At present we have nothing.

Answer (score 0):

To select category that is in item or in label node you could use `//*[self::item or self::label]/category`. That gives you `#cdata-section`, but extracting part of string that's inside CDATA is not a job for xPath as this value is not part of XML structure. Use substring, split string or regex for that.