# C# Convert XML file to Multiple Polygon Objects

Tags: c#, xml, polygon, kml

After converting multiple MapInfo files into a unique Shapefile, and then converting that file again to .KML, I got the following .XML file. My idea is to extract each set of 'coordinates' sections, and build polygons using them.

**Other attempted solution:**

Given the excessive time facing this blockage, I tried obtaining each pair of 'coordinates' tags and using Substring to get the coordinates. Unfortunately given the size of the file (>400 MB) this dirty approach is not practical.

**Xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document id="root_doc">
    <Schema id="PruebaKML4g.schema">
      <SimpleField name="FID" type="float"/>
      <SimpleField name="REGION" type="float"/>
      <SimpleField name="NOMBRE" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="layer" type="string"/>
      <SimpleField name="path" type="string"/>
    </Schema>
    <Document id="PruebaKML4g">
      <name>PruebaKML4g</name>
      <Placemark id="PruebaKML4g.1">
        <ExtendedData>
          <SchemaData schemaUrl="#PruebaKML4g.schema">
            <SimpleData name="FID">5</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="REGION">1</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="NOMBRE">BAJA CALIFORNIA</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="layer">LBS_REGION_1_region</SimpleData>
            <SimpleData name="path">C:/Files/LBS_REGION_1_region.shp</SimpleData>
          </SchemaData>
        </ExtendedData>
        <MultiGeometry>
         <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
              <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                  -105.258751,21.782028,0
                  -105.247174,21.81173,0
                  -105.241826,21.809401,0
                  -105.236994,21.806241,0
                  -105.232822,21.802344,0
                  -105.229439,21.79783,0
                  -105.228552,21.796052,0
                  -105.228974,21.795899,0
                  -105.230294,21.79522,0
                  -105.231872,21.79511,0
                  -105.234048,21.79431,0
                  -105.235131,21.794083,0
                  -105.236824,21.793857,0
                  -105.238518,21.793295,0
                  -105.239365,21.792389,0
                  -105.240327,21.790914,0
                  -105.242379,21.79046,0
                  -105.243829,21.790459,0
                  -105.245644,21.788766,0
                  -105.247331,21.785709,0
                  -105.24817,21.783115,0
                  -105.248701,21.780372,0
                  -105.258751,21.782028,0
                </coordinates>
              </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
          </Polygon>        
...
            <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
              <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                  -103.704559,20.767933,0
                  -103.702714,20.773608,0
                  -103.701694,20.77322,0
                  -103.700762,20.772672,0
                  -103.699944,20.77198,0
                  -103.699267,20.771165,0
                  -103.698751,20.770252,0
                  -103.698411,20.769268,0
                  -103.698258,20.768243,0
                  -103.698297,20.76721,0
                  -103.704559,20.767933,0
                </coordinates>
              </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
          </Polygon>
          <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
              <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                  -105.160778,20.766278,0
                  -105.162411,20.77201,0
                  -105.161328,20.77219,0
                  -105.160228,20.77219,0
                  -105.159145,20.77201,0
                  -105.158111,20.771656,0
                  -105.157159,20.771139,0
                  -105.156317,20.770474,0
                  -105.15561,20.769682,0
                  -105.15506,20.768786,0
                  -105.160778,20.766278,0
                </coordinates>
              </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
          </Polygon>          
          <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
              <LinearRing>
                <coordinates>
                  -117.125814,32.524285,0
                  -117.125516,32.524512,0
                  -117.125142,32.524428,0
                  -117.124876,32.524169,0
                  -117.124754,32.524513,0
                  -117.124784,32.525361,0
          </coordinates>
              </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
          </Polygon>
        </MultiGeometry>
      </Placemark>
    </Document>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

I tried to use the following code:

Main

```
 public T DeserializeToObject<T>(string filepath) where T : class
        {
            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filepath))
            {
                return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String pathKml = @"C:\PruebaKML4g.kml";

            List<Kml> elementsList = DeserializeToObject<List<Kml>>(pathKml);
        }
```

Kml.cs

```
 /*[XmlRoot(ElementName = "kml")] changed by Mike Clark suggestion*/ 
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "kml", Namespace = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2")]
    public class Kml

    {
        public List<Polygon> polygons = new List<Polygon>();
    }

    public class Polygon
    {
        [XmlAttribute("outerBoundaryIs")]
        public String outerBoundaryIs { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("linearRing")]
        public String linearRing { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute("coordinates")]
        public String coordinates { get; set; }
    }
```

However, the SimpleData elements in the XML file appear to be interfering with my parsing, generating the following error

> InvalidOperationException:  xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'> was not expected.

Any clue about where my mistake is will be appreciated.

Comment: Does adding the Namespace attribute to Kml class help? `XmlRoot(ElementName="kml", Namespace="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2")]` ?

Comment: Tried changing the namespace attribute as you suggested, but sadly the error remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With all those conversion steps, perhaps the XML file is malformed? Or maybe a memory error with so much data? Try parsing the file with a low-memory requirement SAX parser to let it find any syntactical errors that might be buried deep in the file. Do you have Python installed?

`python -c "import xml.sax;p=xml.sax.make_parser();p.parse(r'yourfile.xml')"`

Change `yourfile.xml` to the correct path and filename of your XML file.

If it prints nothing, the file is syntactically valid. If it prints an error, try to use the line:column info in the error to spot the error in your XML.

---

Part 2:

`List<Kml> elementsList = DeserializeToObject<List<Kml>>(pathKml);`

might be wrong. XML documents can have one and only one root `<element>` (in this case, `<kml>`) so I think having a list of Kml instances will not make make sense for the parser. Try this instead:

`Kml root = DeserializeToObject<Kml>(pathKml);`

But that is a simple problem compared to the next problem, which is that I think your C# class structure needs to mirror exactly the hierarchical structure of the XML. The polygons are under this hierarchy:

`kml > Document > Document > Placemark > MultiGeometry`

which means you would need something like

```
class Kml {
  Document Document;
}
class Document {
  Document Document;
  Placemark Placemark;
}
class Placemark {
  Polygon[] MultiGeometry;
}
class Polygon {
  OuterBoundaryIs outerBoundaryIs;
}
class OuterBoundaryIs {
  LinearRing LinearRing;
}
class LinearRing {
  string coordinates;
}
```

Then you would need something like

```
var polygons = kml.Document.Document.Placemark.MultiGeometry;
for(int i = 0; i < polygons.Length; i++) {
  var polygon = polygons[i];
  string coordinates = polygon.outerBoundaryIs.LinearRing.coordinates;
  // do something with coordinates
}
```

By the way, a better kind of parser for this type of thing would be an XPath parser which can avoid the need to model the XML structure with C# classes. It takes a little practice and research to craft an XPath query, but the resulting code is cleaner, and it's a good skill to have some experience with. More XPath see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16012736/11611195

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/select-nodes-using-xpath-navigation

Comment: After applying your Python check, the result was empty, so we can conclude that the XML file is valid. I didn't know your XML checking technique, very nice.

Comment: @FelipeLaRotta I added a second part to my answer.